# Validate JWT token in .Net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, .net-6.0, bearer-token

I'm stuck at JWT token validation on my end, our client send us JWT Token with secret key with us to validate the token but I'm unable to validate it, can anyone please help me out and guide me how to validate the JWT Token which is send by client for e.g I have 2 solution A and B using .net6,
A is used for login purpose I used JWT for authentication now i want to validate the JWT token in B using only secret key how can I validate JWT token in B in .NET 6?

Thanks in advance

Comment: but I'm unable to validate it--could you show the error message?